# Inkscape CLI syntax to select objects/paths

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, inkscape

I have the following SVG-file:

```
<svg width="18px" height="18px" viewBox="0 0 18 18" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<title>Kalender</title>
<g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g transform="translate(-178.000000, -704.000000)" stroke="#0067C5">
        <g transform="translate(139.000000, 20.000000)">
            <g transform="translate(36.000000, 681.000000)">
                <polyline points="7 5.66666667 4.33333333 5.66666667 4.33333333 19.6666667 19.6666667 19.6666667 19.6666667 5.66666667 17 5.66666667"></polyline>
                <polygon points="7 4.33333333 9 4.33333333 9 7 7 7"></polygon>
                <polygon points="15 4.33333333 17 4.33333333 17 7 15 7"></polygon>
                <path d="M9,5 L15,5"></path>
                <path d="M4.33333333,9 L19.6666667,9"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

Which consists of a series of objects with strokes which I need to convert to paths.

In the GUI version of Inkscape the solution to my problem is the following steps:

- Select "Edit paths by nodes" tool on the left toolbar (Using the regular selection tool doesn't work)
- Click on an object to select it
- Then go to "Edit > Select Same > Stroke style" (to select all other objects with same stroke)
- Then go to "Path > Stroke to Path"

But I need the CLI syntax for the same operation in order to automate this process for a series of SVG files.

I've tried the following:

```
inkscape -f $1"-stroketopath/"$svgfile --verb="EditSelectAll" --verb="EditSelectSameStrokeStyle" --verb="StrokeToPath" --verb="FileSave" --verb="FileQuit"
```

Which doesn't work. And I suspect it fails for the same reason as noted above (that the "Edit > Select Same > Stroke style" operation doesn't work with the regular selection tool (which is utilized in the "Edit > Select all" operation).

So does anyone know how to replace `--verb="EditSelectAll"` with something that uses the "Edit paths by nodes" tool and then select one or all of the objects in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was to run through all of my SVGs and inject an `id="inkscape"` attribute on the first element of type `path`, `rect`, `circle`, `ellipse`, `line`, `polyline` or `polygon`.

Then I could run:

```
inkscape -f $svgfile --select="inkscape" --verb="EditSelectSameStrokeStyle" --verb="StrokeToPath" --verb="SelectionUnion" --verb="FileSave" --verb="FileQuit"
```

Using the `--select` command ([details here](https://inkscape.org/sk/doc/inkscape-man.html#OPTIONS)).

> The --select command will cause objects that have the ID specified to
>   be selected. This allows various verbs to act upon them. To remove all
>   the selections use --verb=EditDeselect. The object IDs available are
>   dependent on the document specified to load.